# How to equally space items in Xcode storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uikit, interface-builder

I want to have 15 buttons equally spaced between them and correctly leading and trailing the superview vertically. I set constraints so that the left set of buttons aligns to the left margin and the right set aligns to the right margin. The first button leads from the top margin in each set, and the remaining buttons each have a constraint for vertical space set to the upper neighbor. I thought this would be enough to make it work but it wasn't. As you can see, for an iPhone 4, the number of buttons displayed on the screen is only 12 so I would definitely need to somehow dynamically change the button size depending on the screen size. I am attaching a screenshot from the storyboard that shows the `Any x Any` editor view and a preview for the 3.5-inch screen.

[image]

Comment: If you are targeting iOS9 use UIStackView. They are perfect for this kind of layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was really easy to accomplish using stack views. Simply select all the buttons and click the leftmost icon (bottom right side of left pane) which is named Stack, and see the magic happening!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the constraints like this:

First select the all elements on left side and give leading constraint:

[image]

Now select first element and give top constraint:

[image]

Now select the second element and select it , and drag it to first element and give vertical spacing: , repeat giving vertical spacing for all the elements, So that each element will be vertical space constrained with its top element!!.

[image]

Do the same for elements on right side.

Give the trailing constraints for all elements on left,

and the select top element and give top constraint

and then select one element below top element and give vertical spacing between those two, repeat it for all the elements!!! So that each element will be vertical space constrained with its top element!!

**Note**: I only gave left constraints, you can try for right side too!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add height constrain to the top left button to be `1/15` of the superview height and for all buttons let their height equal to the top left one.

**Note** it will work only if the vertical spacing is zero between buttons.

If you have a vertical space value for example `x`, then set it as `1/15` - `14 * x`

**Note #2** in iOS 9 only, seems the stack view will help perfectly in that